# Read CSV file in Pandas with Blank lines in between

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data.csv file like this

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5  
10,12,14,15,16  
18,20,22,24,26  
28,30,32,34,36  
38,40,42,44,46  
48,50,52,54,56

Col6,Col7  
11,12  
13,14  
...
```

Now, I want to read only the data of columns Col1 to Col5 and I don't require Col6 and Col7.

I tried reading this file using

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',header=0)
```

then its throwing an error saying

```
UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec cant decode byte 0xb2 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Then, I tried this

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',header=0,error_bad_lines=True)
```

But this is also not giving the desired result. How can we read only till the first blank line in the csv file?

Comment: Have you tried `encoding = 'utf-16'`?

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is with the file. This is not a valid csv file, but two csv files concatenated into one. Try splitting the file into two files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a generator which reads a file line by line. The result is passed to `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io


def file_reader(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line and line != '\n':
                yield line
            else:
                break


data = io.StringIO(''.join(file_reader('data.csv')))
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas doesn't have an option to stop at a condition, but it does have condition to stop after n rows. So you could read the file first, count number of rows until blank and then load in pandas with

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv',nrows= count )
```

Along the lines of this:

```
count = 0
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line and line != '\n':
            count += 1
        else:
            break

pd.read_csv(filename,nrows=count)
```

Comment: There are many files to read @Christian Sloper. So it would be extremely difficult to count the rows in each file

Comment: Bit hard to understand that comment, you count with the program snippet , just before you load it into pandas.